# Is it possible to setup fiddler to capture requests from QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs, request, fiddler

I want to know if it is possible setup fiddler to capture WMS/WFS requests from QGIS and how to do it.

Fiddler is capturing the requests from MapInfo and I don't remember making any setup in fiddler to accomplish that.

So can I make fiddler capture requests from QGIS and how do I do it?

Version info: Fiddler 2.3.9.5, QGIS 1.7.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fiddler allow you to capture HTTP traffic acting as a proxy between you and network.

So to capture WMS/WFS requests from any software I believe you have just to run Fiddler as usual. The same way you have done it with MapInfo - no additional configuring is required.

PS I have tested it with ArcGIS Server - successfully capturing REST traffic.

EDIT1:

You was right - running fiddler without additional configuration of QGIS did nothing.

I was able to capture traffic from QGIS by navigating to QGIS Settings\Options\Network and checking `Use proxy for web access`. Then I have setup `127.0.0.1` for Host, `8888` for Port and `HttpProxy` for Proxy type.

You can use these parameters too or check what Fiddler had setup in Windows Control Panel\Internet Options\Connections\LAN settings\Advanced

I think this is happening because QGIS is not reading system Internet Properties and MapInfo is reading.

Comment: That was also what I thought I should do, but when I add a WMS layer in QGIS and move the map or zoom in I do not see the requests in fiddler. But when I add a WMS layer in MapInfo and zoom I get all the requests in fiddler.

Comment: Indeed, you was right - additional configuration is required. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Setting QGIS to use a proxy did the trick for me.

Comment: QGIS 2.0 should read the system proxy settings now.

Comment: To clarify Nathan's comment (testing in QGIS 2.2.0), this means that you still have to check the 'Use proxy for web access' option in  Settings > Options, but you don't need to fill in any of the fields.