# How does QGIS extract features from the XML response of an INSPIRE WFS server?

Tags: qgis, wfs, ogr2ogr, xml, inspire

### Context

In QGIS, I add OpenStreetMap as an XYZ layer. I zoom to the [Belgian-Dutch-German tripoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaalserberg). I press `F12` (`fn-F12` on Mac) to get Network Logger up. I add a WFS connection to visualize [North Rhine-Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Rhine-Westphalia)'s parcels ([source website](https://open.nrw/dataset/af87d424-64e9-4d2d-9dd1-b3bd80423209)):

https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis

I choose the `Flurstück` layer. Display at this point:

[image]

I would like to reproduce the creation of the `Flurstück` features using the link to one of the GET requests. The last request:

> 995 GET
> https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=100000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&BBOX=672989.01836707652546465,6580237.92264114506542683,676336.63031239178963006,6583675.5681595616042614,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)

---

### Attempt 1: [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)

Set the link as an environment variable:

```
URL="https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=100000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&BBOX=672989.01836707652546465,6580237.92264114506542683,676336.63031239178963006,6583675.5681595616042614,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
```

Download response:

```
curl $URL -o resp.xml
```

Inspect `resp.xml`:

[image]

Reassuringly, it contains parcel polygons. Try to extract them with `ogr2ogr`:

```
ogr2ogr parcels.geojson resp.xml CadastralParcel
```

Output (via `head -c2000 parcels.geojson`):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "CadastralParcel",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_05417802400487______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_05417802400487______", "areaValue": 64.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2013-03-19T15:07:34Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_05417802400487______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": 487, "nationalCadastralReference": "05417802400487______", "validFrom": "1992-01-01", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 673289.935999999986961, 6582283.457999999634922 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_05417802400652______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_05417802400652______", "areaValue": 9.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2013-03-19T15:07:34Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_05417802400652______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": 652, "nationalCadastralReference": "05417802400652______", "validFrom": "2010-01-01", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 673568.26500000001397, 6582331.541000000201166 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "CadastralParcel_05417802400378______", "identifier": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis/CadastralParcel_05417802400378______", "areaValue": 369.0, "beginLifespanVersion": "2015-05-05T15:35:02Z", "endLifespanVersion": "", "localId": "CadastralParcel_05417802400378______", "namespace": "https://registry.gdi-de.org/id/de.nw.inspire.cp.alkis", "label": 378, "nationalCadastralReference": "05417802400378______", "validFrom": "1985-01-01", "validTo": "", "zoning": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coo
```

Unfortunately, `parcels.geojson` only contains reference points to parcels, and not the parcel coordinates themselves.

---

### Attempt 2: [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) and [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/)

This is clearly a suboptimal workaround. Using Python:

```
import requests
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    "https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&COUNT=100000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&BBOX=669448.51340211916249245,6576908.11438542790710926,673143.3303862038301304,6581970.96679305844008923,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&NAMESPACE=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"
).content, "xml")

coordstrings = [each.text for each in soup.findAll("gml:posList")]

new_coordstrings=[]
for coordstring in coordstrings:
    new_coordstring = ''
    coordstring_split = coordstring.split(' ')
    for index, each in enumerate(coordstring_split):
        new_coordstring += (each)
        if index!=len(coordstring_split)-1:
            if index%2==1:
                new_coordstring += ', '
            else:
                new_coordstring += ' '
    new_coordstrings.append(new_coordstring)

polygon_strings = [f"POLYGON(({new_coordstring}))" for new_coordstring in new_coordstrings]
res=gpd.GeoSeries([shapely.wkt.loads(polygon_string) for polygon_string in polygon_strings],crs=3857)

res.to_file("res.geojson")
```

Visualize `res.geojson` in QGIS:

[image]

So the script did the job, but it is clear this is not what QGIS is doing under the hood.

---

### Question

**How to replicate QGIS and extract the parcel data from the XML file?**

I am certain QGIS does not use BeautifulSoup and such workarounds as I did above. I suspect it uses `ogr2ogr`. If there is a simple programmatic way of extracting the parcel polygons, I am interested even if QGIS is doing it differently.

Having an answer to this question will help me solve [a different but related question of mine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446363/how-to-download-all-parcel-boundaries-of-north-rhine-westphalia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your curl command for downloading test data. Then I checked the layers with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo GMLAS:inspire.xml
```

One of the layers is this

```
8: cadastralparcel (Unknown (any), Point)
```

It seems to contain two geometries, first is of some undefined geometry type, the second one is point. GeoJSON can only have one geometry field and it is not sure what will happen in the conversion but we can try.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON inspirecp.json GMLAS:inspire.xml cadastralparcel
```

Check the result:

```
ogrinfo inspirecp.json -al |more

INFO: Open of `inspirecp.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: cadastralparcel
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3858
Extent: (671494.159000, 6579594.587000) - (676942.858000, 6585030.326000)
...
```

At least there are now parcel polygons in a GeoJSON file.

Comment: I encountered a very similar situation to this one, but strangely this solution did not work. I also encountered situations recently which were similar and the solution worked. I explain what the new challenges are here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448637/how-to-use-wfs-access-point-to-create-geojsons-when-ogr2ogr-does-not-find-a-sche.

Answer (score 2):

List layers

```bash
ogrinfo WFS:"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis"
```

Get infos on the layer you want to retrieve

```
ogrinfo -so WFS:"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis" "cp:CadastralParcel"
```

It returns a "Feature Count: 9355266". It may be better to avoid downloading all the parcels. You can ask gdal utilties to manage paging for you

Filter on an extent (you may also set `-spat_srs` EPSG:yourcode when using `-spat` option). KEPT FOR THE ARCHIVE BUT NOT WORKING: not allowed by remote server...

```bash
ogr2ogr --DEBUG ON \
        -f GPKG \
        cadastral_parcel.gpkg \
        WFS:"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis" \
        "cp:CadastralParcel" \
        --config OGR_WFS_PAGING_ALLOWED ON \
        --config OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE 10000 \
        -nln cadastral_parcel \
        -spat <xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>
```

The same without filtering to get all the layer (brute force approach..., long)

```bash
ogr2ogr --DEBUG ON \
        -f GPKG \
        cadastral_parcel.gpkg \
        WFS:"https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis" \
        "cp:CadastralParcel" \
        --config OGR_WFS_PAGING_ALLOWED ON \
        --config OGR_WFS_PAGE_SIZE 10000 \
        -nln cadastral_parcel
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I launched the second command, and it is still running, despite `STARTINDEX` now being at `12300000`. I expected it to stop after `9355266` but it didn't. What am I missing?

Comment: `HTTP: Fetch(https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_inspire-flurstuecke_alkis?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&STARTINDEX=25400000&COUNT=100000)` - and still running. I'll be curious to see what the end result holds! :)

Comment: I've tried too and wondering if it's not related to infos related returned WFS e.g `No paging support
WFS: No ImplementsStandardJoins support
WFS: No transaction support` (more complete/indented log at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/8a8e02b6da9a4a00f6663ab1711de00a) . Key issue may be the "No paging"